# Google Cloud SQL server no permissions on databases that I created myself through the cloud shell

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-sql

I have created a database on a Cloud SQL server on the Google Cloud (the hosted Microsoft version of SQL) and I log into the sql server instance from my own Linux laptop using `gcloud sql connect` ...so far so good. However, when I want to change to the only database that I created myself and that was not preinstalled, I get the following error:

```
use testdb;

The server principal "jac2130@gmail.com" is not able to access the database "testdb" under the current security context.
```

All of the fixes online that I can find involve using a Windows computer and some Microsoft UI.
I don't have a Windows computer nor any access to anything Microsoft made.

Comment: There are two levels of security here: 1) Server Principals (Windows Logins or SQL Logins) allow you to login to the SQL Server itself; 2) Database Principals (Database Users) grant Server Principals access to databases with particular roles. It sounds as though your SQL Login does not have an appropriate Database User and role in the testdb database. Login with your sa account to fix this by way of [CREATE USER](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql) and [ALTER ROLE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql).

Comment: Thank you; only one problem: how do I log in as the sa user?!